# Select two different Items if they meet different condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select problem with mssql which is;

```
Invoice 1
ItemUniqueNo    ItemName    InvoceNo
1               A           123
3               C           123

Table A (All Invoices)
ItemUniqueNo   ItemName   InvoceNo
1               A           123
2               B           235
3               C           123

Table B (Item List)
ItemUniqueNo    ItemName    ItemGroup
1               A           XXX
2               B           YYY
3               C           ZZZ
```

I want to select every items **(from Table A)** If an invoice has both type of product which is; **ItemUniqueNo=3** and **ItemGroup = XXX**, in same invoice. Here is my code:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
TABLE_A 
WHERE
(ItemUniqueNo IN (SELECT ItemUniqueNo FROM TABLE_B WHERE ItemGroup='XXX') OR ItemUniqueNo = 3)
```

with this code, I've listed all items which has either **ItemGroup = XXX** and **ItemUniqueNo=3** BUT
I want to meet both condition in same invoice, like:

```
Invoice 1
ItemUniqueNo    ItemName    InvoceNo
1               A           123  --->  This meets 'XXX' ItemGroup condition
3               C           123  --->  This meets '3' ItemUniqueNo condition
```

This invoice meet both 2 condition, so i want to list this two item with InvoceNo.
AND all other items which meet this condition.

Comment: Dear friends, I see that a misunderstanding occurs about query. InvoiceNo is the key part of this query. Both two condition connected each other with InvoiceNo. If both condition meets in same invoceNo, then give me just these items (with invoiceNo), otherwise dont give me that item. I mean, if an item has a group of 'XXX' then dont show me it alone. Just show it to me if the same invoice has an item which uniqueNo is '3'. Two items must be in same invoice. i hope i made myself clear.

Comment: Please check the updated answer

Comment: A table line (an item) dependent another table line (in item). One item must has group of 'XXX' , and onether item (another table line) must has ItemUniqueNo of '3'. Both this items mut have sami invoiceNo. Otherwise, dont show that items. So, one item dependent another item in same table with invoiceNo.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a case statement in your where clause instead of 'OR' then your output will be match what you did want before. You can check my answer.

```
Create table TableA (ItemUniqueNo int, ItemName Char(1),  InvoceNo int)
insert into TableA Values
(1, 'A', 123),
(2, 'B', 235),
(3, 'C', 123),
(4, 'A', 999),
(3, 'B', 999)

Create table TableB (ItemUniqueNo int, ItemName Char(1),  ItemGroup Varchar(10))
insert into TableB Values
(1, 'A', 'XXX'),
(2, 'B', 'YYY'),
(3, 'C', 'ZZZ'),
(4, 'A', 'XXX')

SELECT TABLEA.*
  FROM TABLEA INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT TABLEA.INVOCENO
           FROM (SELECT TABLEA.INVOCENO,
                        (CASE
                            WHEN ITEMGROUP = 'XXX' THEN 1
                            WHEN TABLEA.ITEMUNIQUENO = 3 THEN 1
                            ELSE 0
                         END)
                           AS FLAG
                   FROM TABLEA
                        INNER JOIN TABLEB
                           ON CONCAT(TABLEA.ITEMUNIQUENO,TABLEA.ITEMNAME) = CONCAT(TABLEB.ITEMUNIQUENO,TABLEB.ITEMNAME))
                TABLEA
          WHERE FLAG = 1) COND ON TABLEA.INVOCENO = COND.INVOCENO
```

[Here is a dbfiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d8231230442a2dbc0cacd84149d35b49)

[image: Result]

Comment: Sorry for my late response due to my hard work. I could not adapt your query to mine. You use create table function, but my tables exist. So could you please seperate with create part and select part.

Comment: I updated my answer. Could you please check it. @mithderler

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `OR` to an `AND` in your `where` clause

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using inner join as shown below.

```
Create table TableA (ItemUniqueNo int, ItemName Char(1),  InvoceNo int)
insert into TableA Values
(1, 'A', 123),
(2, 'B', 235),
(3, 'C', 123)

Create table TableB (ItemUniqueNo int, ItemName Char(1),  ItemGroup Varchar(10))
insert into TableB Values
(1, 'A', 'XXX'),
(2, 'B', 'YYY'),
(3, 'C', 'ZZZ')

SELECT TableA.*
    ,TableB.ItemGroup
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.ItemUniqueNo = TableB.ItemUniqueNo
WHERE ItemGroup = 'XXX'
    OR TableA.ItemUniqueNo = 3
ORDER BY TableA.ItemUniqueNo
```

Here is the live [db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c90f598155f60c4316a3dd8bdbdc8acf).
Another option you can try this

```
SELECT TableA.*
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT TableA.*
    FROM TableA
    WHERE EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM TableB
            WHERE TableA.ItemName = TableB.ItemName
                AND TableA.ItemName = 'A'
            )
        AND EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM TableB
            WHERE TableA.ItemName = TableB.ItemName
                AND TableB.ItemGroup = 'XXX'
            )
    ) TEMP ON TableA.InvoceNo = TEMP.InvoceNo
```

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=32be5ffc1893f8b4e931ebe058fb1ded

Comment: I've added two more items with different invoceNo. Result must show me four items as: 1-3 (same invoiceNo) and 3-4 (same invoiceNo). But the result shows just three items. Because query dont match invoice condition. An invoice must contain two conditions.

Comment: What is the expected output for  your dbfiddle demo?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, I am so busy nowadays. I tried your code but it gave empty result.

Comment: Please check the demo.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select * from [Table A] A
join [Table B]  B on A.ItemUniqueNo=B.ItemUniqueNo
where b.ItemGroup='XXX' or OR A.ItemUniqueNo = 3
```

Comment: This query doesnt meet invoiceNo equation condition. My code is getting same result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fulfill both conditions at once use AND keyword.  If you want to fulfill only one condition out of two, use OR keyword.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_A 
WHERE ItemUniqueNo IN 
(SELECT ItemUniqueNo 
FROM TABLE_B 
WHERE ItemGroup='XXX' AND ItemUniqueNo = 3)
```

Comment: it doesnt work, because ItemUniqueNo = 3 doesnt have an itemGroup of 'XXX'.  These are two different items.

Comment: I misunderstood your question. I'll update the answer in a while